# Where do I need to receiving Remote push messages in the app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I check for new message in AppDelegate class in 3 places, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` using code:

```
 if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary != nil)
        {
            //NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
            //notification pending ... so pull from server the new message
             [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary updateUI:YES];
        }
    }
```

and in `didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo` using code:

```
// notification pending ... so pull from server the new message
[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo updateUI:YES];
```

and in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` using code

```
if(application.applicationIconBadgeNumber>0)
    {

         application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
         // notification pending ... so pull from server the new message
         [self openMessageViewForNewMessage];


    }
```

However, still I notice there is some cases where my app still dont "catch" notification, meaning, it still not aware that it receive notification. Did I message something? or I should all the time check "my server" for new messages becouse app might not all the times be informed by iOS that there is new notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick overview...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Here you specify what kind of notifications you want your app to receive. For Example, if you want badge, sound and alert you would include this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

In the:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

You can add something like this to make sure to update your badge:

```
NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [badge intValue];
```

I personally also add this code and do my processing where appropriate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedNotificationAlert" object:self];
```

The above works well for all my apps. You mentioned there are some cases when your app misses APNs. Can you share exactly what kind of cases?